# Can’t display images in a table view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiimage

I'm trying to set the image for the cell in a tableview by code. I have all the pictures in an subdirectory of a folder in my mainbundle (Øvelser/Pictures) and from the NSLog() is can see that all the pictures in the array, but the app won't get them. Code and crash report below:

```
 @implementation STATableViewController
 @synthesize nameOfExercises = _nameOfExercises;
 @synthesize exercisePicture = _exercisePicture;

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
[super viewDidLoad];    

//will get the name of the files in the exercise folder
_nameOfExercises = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Øvelser/Text"]error: nil];  

 _exercisePicture = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Øvelser/Pictures"]error: nil]; 

NSLog(@"%@", _nameOfExercises);
NSLog(@"%@", _exercisePicture);

 }     

 - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
return [_nameOfExercises count];
 }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
//the extension is removed, before it's set to the labeltext
NSString *cellValue = [[_nameOfExercises objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringByDeletingPathExtension];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
cell.imageView.image = [_exercisePicture objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 


return cell;
 }
```

console:

```
2012-04-02 14:31:58.324 STA[9665:11f03] (
"Fisketelefon.txt",
"Krammebamse.txt",
"Raketstart.txt"
)

2012-04-02 14:31:58.326 STA[9665:11f03] (
"Fisketelefon.jpg",
"Krammebamse.jpg",
"Raketstart.jpg"
)
2012-04-02 14:31:58.329 STA[9665:11f03] -[__NSCFString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x785d5e0
2012-04-02 14:31:58.330 STA[9665:11f03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception     'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString _isResizable]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x785d5e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14b7052 0x1a6bd0a 0x14b8ced 0x141df00 0x141dce2 0x4ed91b 0x3290 0x49de0f 0x49e589 0x489dfd 0x498851     0x443301 0x14b8e72 0xe792d 0xf1827 0x77fa7 0x79ea6 0x10530c 0x4034c6 0x403bd6 0x412743 0x4131f8 0x406aa9 0x23a4fa9 0x148b1c5 0x13f0022 0x13ee90a 0x13eddb4 0x13edccb 0x4032a7 0x404a9b 0x23f8 0x2355)
terminate called throwing an exceptionwarning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block     that isn't in the frame.
warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.
warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.
warning: Attempting to create USE_BLOCK_IN_FRAME variable with block that isn't in the frame.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to assign an image (an instance of the `UIImage` class) into the `imageView.image` property. But what you’re storing there is a name of the file that holds the image. You have to turn the file name into an actual image:

```
NSString *pathPrefix = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]
    stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Øvelser/Pictures"];
NSString *imageName = [_exercisePicture objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *fullImagePath = [pathPrefix stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];
[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullImagePath]];
```

Comment: the app doesn't crash anymore, but it still won't show the pictures. I know that the folder than i reference in the _exercisePictures does contain pictures, but do i only get the name of those pictures?

Comment: Ah yes, you have to pass the whole path to the `initWithContentsOfFile:` initializer, otherwise it won’t be able to load the image.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that?

Comment: I’ve updated the code sample, that should work & make things clear.

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess:

The objects in `_exercisePicture` are strings. And then you try to set an image to the string:

```
cell.imageView.image = [_exercisePicture objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Please make sure that the objects in `_exercisePicture` are images.

Hope it helps